# How to debug Boost tuple error "no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type"

Tags: c++, boost

I have a boost::tuple list and I am using remove method to remove one of the entries from that list. But I am getting the following error. How can I get rid of this?

> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\algorithm(40) : error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'boost::tuples::tuple' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: It's good that you've given us the error - some question don't even give _that!_ Now all we need is to see the code that caused the error :-)

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an extra header for the comparisons

```
#include "boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp"
```

see this link

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#using_library